# Using MACRO for creating strings (e.g. array index) dynamically inside a for loop

Tags: c++, macros

I want to dynamically create strings using MACRO. e.g. if I have int i in range of 1:n and string "testArray". I should be able to create testArray[0],testArray[1], ... testarray[n-1]
Please let me know if it is possible.

Below is sample code :

```
void fun2(int x,std::string name)
{
/*do something*/
}

void fun1()
{

  for (unsigned int i = 0 ;i < 5 ; ++i )
    {
        // I want to create a MACRO such that it create "testArray[0]","testArray[1]",..."testArray[4]" etc.
        fun2(x,CREATE_ARRAY_ELEM ("testArray",i));
    }
 }
```

I tried below but it does not work :

```
#define STR1(x) #x
#define CREATE_INDEX(paramName,elementIndex) #paramName << "[" << elementIndex << "]"
#define CREATE_ARRAY_ELEM(paramName,elementIndex) CREATE_INDEX(paramName,elementIndex)
#define STRINGIZE_1(x) STR1(x)
```

Comment: "Using MACRO for creating strings (e.g. array index) dynamically" is typically not the way to go, since C++ is not assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be wanting to create the string *literals* "testArray[0]", "testArray[1]", etc.. at compile time. Thats not going to happen. You could easily accomplish this at *runtime* using an `ostringstream`, but I don't think that is what you're looking for.

If it *is* what you're looking for, then...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

static std::string array_str(const char* s, unsigned int i)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << s << '[' << i << ']';
    return oss.str();
}

void fun2(int x, const std::string& name)
{
    std::cout << x << ':' << name << std::endl;
}

void fun1()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ;i < 5 ; ++i )
    {
        fun2(i, array_str("testArray", i));
    }
}
```

**Test Output**

```
0:testArray[0]
1:testArray[1]
2:testArray[2]
3:testArray[3]
4:testArray[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this..means in macros itself you have to display the desired string ..

```
    #include<iostream>

    #define STR1(x) #x
    #define CREATE_INDEX(paramName,elementIndex) cout <<paramName<< "[" << elementIndex    << "]"
    #define CREATE_ARRAY_ELEM(paramName,elementIndex)      CREATE_INDEX(paramName,elementIndex)
    #define STRINGIZE_1(x) STR1(x)

    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    int testArray;
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ;i < 5 ; ++i )
    {
    // I want to create a MACRO such that it create  "testArray[0]","testArray[1]",..."testArray[4]" etc.
    CREATE_ARRAY_ELEM ("testArray",i);

    }
    return 1;
     }
```